IntelliSense fails to deduct template arguments when passing the result of "new" to a template function
In the below code snippet IntelliSense fails with the following error:
no instance of function template "some_template_function" matches the argument list C/C++(304)
template.cpp(10, 14): argument types are: (<error-type>)

#include <string>

template <class T> T* some_template_function(T *param)
{
    return param;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int *x = some_template_function(new int());      // does NOT work
    int *y = some_template_function<int>(new int()); // works
}

However, removing the #include <string> makes IntelliSense work fine again, so there is no error in this snippet:
template <class T> T* some_template_function(T *param)
{
    return param;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int *x = some_template_function(new int());      // works
    int *y = some_template_function<int>(new int()); // works
}

Also, if I don't pass the result of new int() to some_template_function directly, but instead store it in a temp variable IntelliSense works fine as well, even with the #include <string>:
#include <string>

template <class T> T* some_template_function(T *param)
{
    return param;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int *temp = new int();
    int *x = some_template_function(temp);      // works
    int *y = some_template_function<int>(temp); // works
}

I am getting this IntelliSense error in VS Code (C/C++ extension v1.21.6) on macOS (14.6) since a yesterday when my Xcode was updated to 16.0 (16A242d).
Also, actually compiling the file works just fine as well, regardless of which of the three versions I use.
I also tried all kinds of intelliSenseMode and compilerPath variations in VSCode, nothing seems to do the trick.

Try Clangd instead of the official C/C++ plugin.
